# Instance of list in ArrayField valid?

Tags: python, django

I have some user accounts with the field "donation_methods". A user can choose between different methods to accept donations. By default, every user should have the value 'cash' in the array

```
donation_methods = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        choices=DONATION.CHOICES,
    ),
    default=list({DONATION.CASH}),
)
```

Is this the correct way to do this because it's an instance and not a callable?

Comment: No....its not....

Comment: @VaibhavVishal But it's working and I don't get an error message.

Comment: Then why bother asking question on SO

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Because the documentation says you should use a callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) expects a callable for **default**:

> If you give the field a default, ensure it’s a callable such as list
>   (for an empty default) or a callable that returns a list (such as a
>   function)

Then you could define the following function:

```
def donation_default():
    return [DONATION.CASH]
```

Then set your field as:

```
donation_methods = ArrayField(
    models.CharField(
    max_length=15,
    choices=DONATION.CHOICES,
    ),
    default=donation_default,
)
```